# Continuous deployment with github and azure function project in visual studio 2017 preview

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

I am trying to set ci/cd from github to azure functions
I created an Azure function project in git "https://github.com/AmitayStrijevski/AppFunctionTest".

I published it once through the visual studio and it worked perfect.

Then i connected it to the github ci/cd described here 
"https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-continuous-deployment#continuous-deployment-requirements".

When pushing to git i can see it takes my code and "deploy" it but when i look at the the functions my new code is not there and the logs show the following message

"Found solution 'D:\home\site\repository\HeyArnold\HeyArnold.sln' with no deployable projects. Deploying files instead."

I spent  more than a day on this and i will really appreciate help in this issue

I was able to use the github deployment when using an empty web site and setting the same folder structure generated by the azure portal
This is still not solve my problem because i want to use Azure function project but i thought worth mentioning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After consulting with Microsoft support i recevied two files that needed to be put in the .sln folder and then git deployment will work

Be aware changing lines
:: 1. Restore nuget packages
:: 2. Build and publish
With your solution and project actual name

- .deployment

  `[config]
  command = deploy.cmd`
- deployment.cmd

  @if "%SCM_TRACE_LEVEL%" NEQ "4" @echo off

  :: ----------------------
  :: KUDU Deployment Script
  :: Version: 1.0.15
  :: ----------------------

  :: Prerequisites
  :: -------------

  :: Verify node.js installed
  where node 2>nul >nul
  IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
    echo Missing node.js executable, please install node.js, if already installed make sure it can be reached from current environment.
    goto error
  )

  :: Setup
  :: -----

  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

  SET ARTIFACTS=%~dp0%..\artifacts

  IF NOT DEFINED DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE (
    SET DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE=%~dp0%.
  )

  IF NOT DEFINED DEPLOYMENT_TARGET (
    SET DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=%ARTIFACTS%\wwwroot
  )

  IF NOT DEFINED NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH (
    SET NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH=%ARTIFACTS%\manifest

  IF NOT DEFINED PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH (
      SET PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH=%ARTIFACTS%\manifest
    )
  )

  IF NOT DEFINED KUDU_SYNC_CMD (
    :: Install kudu sync
    echo Installing Kudu Sync
    call npm install kudusync -g --silent
    IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

  :: Locally just running "kuduSync" would also work
    SET KUDU_SYNC_CMD=%appdata%\npm\kuduSync.cmd
  )

  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
  :: Deployment
  :: ----------
  echo Handling function App deployment with Custom script.

  :: 1. Restore nuget packages
  call :ExecuteCmd nuget.exe restore "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\FunctionAppVS2017_3Preview.sln" -MSBuildPath "D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild-15.3-preview\MSBuild\15.0\Bin"
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

  :: 2. Build and publish
  call :ExecuteCmd "D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild-15.3-preview\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%FunctionApp1\FunctionApp1.csproj" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:configuration=Release /p:publishurl="%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%" %SCM_BUILD_ARGS%
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

  :: 3. KuduSync
  IF /I "%IN_PLACE_DEPLOYMENT%" NEQ "1" (
    call :ExecuteCmd "%KUDU_SYNC_CMD%" -v 50 -f "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%" -t "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%" -n "%NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH%" -p "%PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH%" -i ".git;.hg;.deployment;deploy.cmd"
    IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
  )

  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
  goto end

  :: Execute command routine that will echo out when error
  :ExecuteCmd
  setlocal
  set *CMD*=%*
  call %*CMD*%
  if "%ERRORLEVEL%" NEQ "0" echo Failed exitCode=%ERRORLEVEL%, command=%*CMD*%
  exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%

  :error
  endlocal
  echo An error has occurred during web site deployment.
  call :exitSetErrorLevel
  call :exitFromFunction 2>nul

  :exitSetErrorLevel
  exit /b 1

  :exitFromFunction
  ()

  :end
  endlocal
  echo Finished successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Check out `<functionappname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev` to see what files are actually deployed to the `wwwroot` folder.

I took a look at your github project and I noticed a few things: if you're using `.cs` files, you should be creating a [precompiled function](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/03/16/publishing-a-net-class-library-as-a-function-app/), which you can deploy directly from VS.

However, if you're instead using `.csx` files and want to be able to edit code from the functions portal, the structure you have is correct - just remove the solution and csproj files, as I believe they are confusing the deployment infrastructure

Comment: Matt thanks for your answer
It uploads the whole repository into the site.
I want to be able to code in visual studio commit and auto deploy to my function

Answer (score 0):

I'm using VSTS rather than GitHub but you might still find this link [here](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/291) of use.

Using the tooling extension for Azure Functions in VS2017 Preview, along with the build steps described in this issue I've been able to get this CI pipeline going with an Azure functions project. Josh Carlisle has detailed the steps to get this up and running on his [blog](https://www.joshcarlisle.io/blog/2017/5/17/visual-studio-2017-tools-for-azure-functions-and-continuous-integration-with-vsts).

Answer (score 0):

You can [add a `.deployment`-file](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments#deploying-a-specific-folder-for-a-node-php-or-aspnet-site) to the **root of your repository** and point Azure, and Kudu, to the correct project-path:

`[config]
project = src/PathToYourProject`

Or you can [add a *Application settings* in the Azure Portal](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments#using-app-settings-instead-of-a-deployment-file) with the key `PROJECT` and the value pointing to the correct project-path.